# How to close window on Button Click and Update Table in the Main Window in PyQT?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a table in my MainWindow in which the data is coming from the MySQL Database.

There is a push button to add new item in that table. When you click on the Push Button, a new Window opens which contains the form. Once you have filled the form, and you press a "Add Section" button on the second window, it is supposed to perform these three things,

1. Insert the Given data back into the Database (**this is working**)
2. Close the Second Window (not working)
3. Update the Table in the Main Window with the new record.

Now, this is the basic function, which is getting the record from the database and displaying it in the Table on MainWindow,

```
def get_section_data(self):
        mycursor = self.DB.cursor()
        Subquery = "Select * from tbl_section"
        mycursor.execute(Subquery)

        numcols = len(mycursor.fetchall()[0])
        mycursor.execute(Subquery)
        numrows = len(mycursor.fetchall())
        self.ui.section_table.setRowCount(numrows)
        self.ui.section_table.setColumnCount(numcols)
        mycursor.execute(Subquery)
        tablerow = 0
        for row in mycursor.fetchall():
            tablecol = 0
            while tablecol < numcols:
                self.ui.section_table.setItem(tablerow, tablecol, PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[tablecol])))
                tablecol += 1
            tablerow += 1
```

this is the function which gets called when you click on "Add Section" on the Main Window (this opens the New Form)

```
def executeAddSectionPage(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.add_section_form = Ui_Add_Section_Window()
        self.add_section_form.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()
        self.add_section_form.section_add_form_button.clicked.connect(self.insert_section_info)
```

Following is the function which is called when you click on the "Add Section" in the 2nd form,

```
 def insert_section_info(self):
        id = self.add_section_form.section_id_add.text()
        name = self.add_section_form.section_name_add.text()
        mycursor = self.DB.cursor()
        sql = "Insert into tbl_section (section_id, section_name) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        val = (int(id), name)
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        self.DB.commit()
        # self.add_section_form.hide() -> I tried to add this but it didn't work
```

When I click on the "Add Section" button on my second window, it doesn't do anything (except storing the record in the database at backend)
When I again click on it, it crashes both the windows.

How can I perform the functionalities that I require?

Following is the complete code of my main.py

```
## IMPORTS
import sys
import os
import PySide2
import mysql.connector as mc
from qt_material import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from add_section_page import Ui_Add_Section_Window
#####################################

# Import GUI File
from ui_interface import *
######################################

# class Add_Section(QMainWindow):
#     def __init__(self):
#         super(Add_Section, self).__init__()
#         self.uic.loadUi('add_section_page.ui', self)

## Main Window Class
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        try:
            self.DB = mc.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="timetable_manager")
        except mc.Error as e:
            print("Error")

        # Load Style Sheet
        apply_stylesheet(app, theme="dark_cyan.xml")

        # Remove Window Title Bar
        self.setWindowFlags(PySide2.QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        # Set main background to transparent
        self.setAttribute(PySide2.QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        # Shadow Style Effect
        self.shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
        self.shadow.setBlurRadius(50)
        self.shadow.setXOffset(0)
        self.shadow.setYOffset(0)
        self.shadow.setColor(QColor(0, 92, 157, 550))
        
        # Apply shadow to central widget 
        self.ui.centralwidget.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)

        self.setWindowIcon(PySide2.QtGui.QIcon(":/icons/airplay.svg"))
        # Set Window Title
        self.setWindowTitle("Timetable Manager")

        # Window Size grip to resize window
        QSizeGrip(self.ui.size_grip)

        # Minimize Window
        self.ui.minimize_window_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.showMinimized())

        # Close Window
        self.ui.close_window_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())

        # Maximize Window
        self.ui.restore_window_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.restore_or_maximize_window())
        
        # Navigate to Section Page 
        self.ui.section_menu_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.section_page))
        self.ui.course_menu_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.course_page))
        
        self.ui.add_section_button.clicked.connect(self.executeAddSectionPage)


        self.show()
        self.get_section_data()


    def executeAddSectionPage(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.add_section_form = Ui_Add_Section_Window()
        self.add_section_form.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()
        self.add_section_form.section_add_form_button.clicked.connect(self.insert_section_info)

        
    def insert_section_info(self):
        id = self.add_section_form.section_id_add.text()
        name = self.add_section_form.section_name_add.text()
        mycursor = self.DB.cursor()
        sql = "Insert into tbl_section (section_id, section_name) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        val = (int(id), name)
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        self.DB.commit()
        # self.add_section_form.hide() -> I tried to add this but it didn't work 
    def get_section_data(self):
        mycursor = self.DB.cursor()
        Subquery = "Select * from tbl_section"
        mycursor.execute(Subquery)

        numcols = len(mycursor.fetchall()[0])
        mycursor.execute(Subquery)
        numrows = len(mycursor.fetchall())
        self.ui.section_table.setRowCount(numrows)
        self.ui.section_table.setColumnCount(numcols)
        mycursor.execute(Subquery)
        tablerow = 0
        for row in mycursor.fetchall():
            tablecol = 0
            while tablecol < numcols:
                self.ui.section_table.setItem(tablerow, tablecol, PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[tablecol])))
                tablecol += 1
            tablerow += 1


    def restore_or_maximize_window(self):
        if self.isMaximized():
            self.showNormal()
            #self.ui.restore_window_button.setIcon()
        else:
            self.showMaximized()
            #self.ui.restore_window_button.setIcon()

    #def get_section_data(self):
        # sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_section"
        # cur = self.db.cursor()
        # for row in cur.execute(sqlquery):
        #     print(row)

## EXECUTE APP  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I tried to add ui files for both the Windows but unfortunately could not add them due to the limit of characters in the Post

Comment: Typo: `self.add_section_form` is a form class (a basic python object that is used to setup the ui), not a widget. Change to `self.window.close()`

Comment: Thank you :( that was such a rookie mistake. Thank you for correcting it.